# Issue with maxWorkerThreads and thread count

Tags: iis-7, iis-6, asp.net, .net, multi-threading

I have created an ASP.net application which creates thread in infinite loop.
And set maxWorkerThreads to 20 in processmodel in machine.config.

When i checked Thread count in perfmon there was around 7000 threads created in worker process.

Or how can we restrict thread creation in ASP.net with IIS6/7.

Answer (score 0):

If the app isn't using the ThreadPool, that setting won't apply. Also, I believe the app can set that value itself if it chooses -- machine.config won't override explicit programmatic parameters.

Is this an app you have source for, or a third-party app you can't get under the hood of?